# Migrating react-router v3 to v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm currently trying to migrate react-router from v3 to v4, but I can't quite grasp the new concepts, my old react-router v3 code looks like this, can someone please take a look and give me some hints?

Thanks!

```
<Router history={ browserHistory }>
     <Route path="/" component={ App }>
       <IndexRoute name="index" component={ Index } />
       <Route name="documents" path="/documents" component={ Documents } onEnter={ authenticate } />
       <Route name="newDocument" path="/documents/new" component={ NewDocument } onEnter={ authenticate } />
       <Route name="editDocument" path="/documents/:_id/edit" component={ EditDocument } onEnter={ authenticate } />
       <Route name="viewDocument" path="/documents/:_id" component={ ViewDocument } onEnter={ authenticate } />
       <Route name="login" path="/login" component={ Login } />
       <Route name="recover-password" path="/recover-password" component={ RecoverPassword } />
       <Route name="reset-password" path="/reset-password/:token" component={ ResetPassword } />
       <Route name="signup" path="/signup" component={ Signup } />
       <Route path="*" component={ NotFound } />
     </Route>
   </Router>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Don't nest routes.**

---

Keep this part

```
<Router history={ browserHistory }>
  <Route path="/" component={ App } />
</Router>
```

and move all the nesting into `<App />` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43311025/2762747)). Also react-router-v4 doesn't have the concept of `<IndexRoute />` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42751770/2762747)).

---

Check out the [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic), it is incredible.

Comment: Thanks! will try it! PD: docs are extremely messed up for me! jajaja

Comment: have a look at the examples at the top :)

Comment: With your answer in mind, I was able to upgrade base boilerplate from the-meteor-chef https://github.com/mgscreativa/base take a look at imports/ui/layouts/App.js